# Can I assign leads automatically using a Form field?

Tags: assignment-rules, web2lead

We have a Lead Form on our website, which generates leads in SF.

In the form, there will be a dropdown with the lead owner (SF value), when the lead is collected in SF, I need that the assignment will be according to that drop down field.

- This should be automatic - I don't want to use assignment rules - as the parameters change all the time. (the leads owner is a very dynamic list with our org)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If your dropdown values have the OwnerID values (or something you could find via SOQL) you could set them via trigger.

1. Have the dropdown map to a custom field on the Lead
2. Have the Lead set to a default owner
3. Have the trigger inspect the custom field and update the OwnerID appropriately